# Understanding the output from the "findOne" query for mongosh cli (mongo shell)

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongo-shell

I need to identify records that have both **balance** property (exists) and **cat_id** property set to a **value**. I basically want to check if such a record exists in the collection.

I ran this first query:

```
db.groups_transactions_categories.findOne({"group_id": ObjectId("6506111291c30eed7c504d3b")}, {"categories": {"$elemMatch": {"$and": [{"cat_id": ObjectId("6506111291c30eed7c504d3c")}, {"balance": {"$exists": true}}]}}})
```

And I get the following output which I want:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId("6506111291c30eed7c504d3d"),
  categories: [
    {
      cat_id: ObjectId("6506111291c30eed7c504d3c"),
      name: 'main account',
      payment_type: 'monthly',
      created_at: ISODate("2023-09-16T20:33:22.557Z"),
      balance: Decimal128("8700")
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I set the filter to `{balance: {"$exists": false}}` and expected a **none** return since I am looking for a record that has both **cat_id** and **balance** set. But it returns the document **id** and not none.

```
db.groups_transactions_categories.findOne({"group_id": ObjectId("6506111291c30eed7c504d3b")}, {"categories": {"$elemMatch": {"$and": [{"cat_id": ObjectId("6506111291c30eed7c504d3c")}, {"balance": {"$exists": false}}]}}})
```

This is returned:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("6506111291c30eed7c504d3d") }
```

I am using pymongo lib in my code if this matters. I need to either return **null** or **none**, or a document so I can process the next part of my logic. I need clarification.

Comment: You're incorrectly specifying two arguments to the `findOne()` function. Presently you're only filtering on the first object and the second one is being interpreted as a projection. Combine them into a single object to pass as a single argument to the command

Comment: @user20042973 oh dear didn't see that ... thanks for the pointer

Comment: Just to be clear George. In the first query you did nothing wrong. You found a document and then projected the `categories` field only if your `$elemMatch` condition was met with two `$and` conditions. In the second query it was the same query so you got the same document back but this time your projection did not display the `categories` field because the second part of your `$and` was false. It would appear you need to all of those conditions in the query if you don't want a document back.